# Xamarin Forms : This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I am trying to run my application it throws the below error.

> {System.NotImplementedException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.
>         at Plugin.Permissions.CrossPermissions.get_Current () [0x00012] in :0 
>         at XamarinStart.Detail+d__4.MoveNext () [0x00032] in D:\AmanahWork\XamarinStart\XamarinStart\XamarinStart\XamarinStart\Detail.xaml.cs:78 }

I have installed `Plugin.Permissions` in the main project also I have tried installing the reference to the Android and iOS project also but still, I am getting the same error.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean with "installing the reference"?

Comment: **Plugin.Permissions** this reference also i have installed in android and iOS but still showing the same error.

Comment: Is this happening for both Android and iOS? What is the compile target for your Android project?

Comment: Do you have some decompile tool? Check is it implemented or not

Comment: i am just trying to debug on Android , compile target is Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) @RuudKobes

Comment: I don't have any decompile tool, can you please help me to fix this issue @DmitryZinoviev

Comment: changing compile android version to  pie 9.0 solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum compile target is `MonoAndroid 7.1` for the current version of this plugin. You have to set this as the compile target in the settings of your project, or use an [older version of the plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions/2.2.1).

The error message is not really helpful but the NuGet page shows the dependency requirements: [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions)

This is also explained by the plugin developer in the issue linked below :
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/issues/111

Comment: @RuddKobes thank you for the support i just update my dependency  for `MonoAndroid 6.0` and it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the Nuget package on both the main project as well as the platform projects.

You also need to add some initialization code, at least on Android, as pointed out on the project's website:

> This plugin uses the [Current Activity Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md) to get access to the
>   current Android Activity. Be sure to complete the full setup if a
>   MainApplication.cs file was not automatically added to your
>   application. Please fully read through the Current Activity Plugin
>   Documentation. At an absolute minimum you must set the following in
>   your Activity's OnCreate method:
>
> Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this,
>   bundle);

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: I have tried adding  `Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);` in Main Activity.cs in Android project but still it shows the same error. can you please help me to fix this issue.